# Fbx Converter Error

Tags: libgdx, blender, fbx

I am using the fbx converter to convert a fbx file I created using Blender. But when I run the converter on my file it gives me an error.

I can give you the .blend and .fbx files too.

http://www.megafileshare.com/s/download/154980/z51592/grass.fbx This is the fbx file
http://www.megafileshare.com/s/download/1513071/z51592/Grass.jpg this is the texture I am using on the object

http://www.megafileshare.com/s/download/3557036/z51592/grass.blend this is the .blend file

Also when I render other objects that i converted using fbx converter , they wont render properly.

[image: ERROR]

Hope someone can tell me what's going on.I just really want to be able to use the objects I create using blender.